# Cant Access Data in List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to access some data within nested ordered dictionaries. This dictionary was created by using the XMLTODICT module. Obviously I would like to create my own dictionaries but this one is out of my control.

I've tried to access them numerous ways.

Example:

Using a for loop:

I can access the first level using `v["name"]` which gives me Child_Policy and Parent Policy

When I do `v["class"]["name"]` I would expect to get "Test1" but that's not the case.

I've also tried `v[("class", )]` variations as well with no luck.

Any input would be much appreciated

The data below is retrieved from a device via XML and converted to dictionary with XMLTODICT.

```py
[
  {
    "@xmlns": "http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-policy",
    "name": "Child_Policy",
    "class": [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "action-list": {
          "action-type": "bandwidth",
          "bandwidth": {
            "percent": "30"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "action-list": {
          "action-type": "bandwidth",
          "bandwidth": {
            "percent": "30"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@xmlns": "http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-policy",
    "name": "Parent_Policy",
    "class": {
      "name": "class-default",
      "action-list": [
        {
          "action-type": "shape",
          "shape": {
            "average": {
              "bit-rate": "10000000"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "action-type": "service-policy",
          "service-policy": "Child_Policy"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

My expectations result is to retrieve values from the nested dictionary and produce and output similar to this:

```
Queue_1:        Test1
Action_1:       bandwidth
Allocation_1:   40


Queue_2:        Test2
Action_2:       bandwidth

Allocation_2:   10
```

I have now issue formatting the output, just getting the values is the issue.

#

I had some time tonight so I changed the code be be dynamic:

```
    int = 0
    int_2 = 0
    for v in policy_dict.values():
        print("\n")
        print("{:15} {:<35}".format("Policy: ", v[0]["name"]))
        print("_______")
        for i in v:
            int_2 = int_2 + 1
            try:
                print("\n")
                print("{:15} {:<35}".format("Queue_%s: " % int_2, v[0]["class"][int]["name"]))
                print("{:15} {:<35}".format("Action_%s: " % int_2, v[0]["class"][int]["action-list"]["action-type"]))
                print("{:15} {:<35}".format("Allocation_%s: " % int_2, v[0]["class"][int]["action-list"]["bandwidth"]["percent"]))
                int = int + 1
            except KeyError:
                break
                pass
```

Comment: According to the representation v["class"] is a list, therefore  v["class"][0]["name"] should work.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but it didn't work. I got the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thanks for the input Michael Butscher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sample you posted you can try to retrieve values like:

```
v[0]["class"][0]["name"]
```

This outputs:

```
Test1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get the expect results. You've helped me solve the thorn in my side which has been there for a while. Always learning.

Comment: @ChrisO Do you understand what the issue was now?

Comment: Yes, so this is a list of dictionaries. The first [0] is the list that has all the dictionaries, or main list .  The second [0] how to access the 1st index of the main  list which is “class.” The [1] is how to access the 2nd index of the main list which is also “class”